# C# order of values calculated in parallel in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a specific `Image[]` created from `byte[]`. Here is the code in LINQ:

```
    return thumbnails.AsParallel()
                     .Select(t => FromByteArray(t))
                     .ToArray()
```

Here is the code of the used method:

```
    public static Image FromByteArray(byte[] arr)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arr))
            return new Bitmap(ms);
    }
```

Will it always work? And will the order be preserved?

**EDIT**

How to preserve the order?

Comment: Parallelism contradicts with preserving the order of execution.

Comment: @EZI No it does not, you can do things in parallel but preserve order. The only limitation is you can't (easily) have a "streamed result" in parallel and preserve order.

Comment: @Randolph your syntax is very weird to me, mixing the two styles. I don't know if that even works or not. However I do know `thumbnails.AsParallel().Select(t=>FromByteArray(t)).ToArray()` would work. (Still not sure if that preserves order though)

Comment: Okay, I changed it to the suggested form :)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I really want to see an example for this. Where taskN should be executed before taskN+1 and they are executed in parallel.

Comment: @EZI I never said they would be processed in order, only the output of said processing could be the same order as the input of said processing (Which is what the OP is looking for confirmation of, that the order of the `Image[]` will be the same order as the `IEnumerable<byte[]>`). EDIT: Rereading your original comment you were talking about preserving execution order, not output order. The OP does not care about the execution order.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain *Reordering the results after parallel execution* doesn't mean *preserving the order of execution* So My initial comment still holds.

Comment: Yes, I don't care about the execution order, I only want the output array to be of the same order as the input.

Comment: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Randolph After reading the MSDN a bit it looks like your orginal syntax would have done the query in parallel after all (I just never use that syntax much).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, no it will not preserve order. However all you need to do is add [`.AsOrdered()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413357(v=vs.100).aspx) and it then will preserve order.

```
return thumbnails.AsParallel()
                 .AsOrdered()
                 .Select(t => FromByteArray(t))
                 .ToArray()
```

or, using your original syntax

```
return (from t in thumbnails.AsParallel().AsOrdered()
        select FromByteArray(t))
        .ToArray();
```

See the MSDN Article "[Order Preservation in PLINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)" for more detailed information (thanks [Ian Mercer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919922/c-sharp-order-of-values-calculated-in-parallel-in-linq/28920158#comment46097733_28919922) for the link)